# How can I create a page in voyager without BREAD?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I need to create a page in the admin menu to generate reports from other data in the database. For example: /admin/reports. I want reports to only have access to administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this

**Add browse_reports permission From sql**

```
INSERT INTO `permissions` (`key`, `table_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `permission_group_id`) VALUES ('browse_reports', NULL, '2018-04-18 12:00:00', '2018-04-18 12:00:00', NULL);
```

Give this permission to the **admin**

Check this permission access to the method which is called for /admin/reports

**In controller**

```
Voyager::canOrFail('browse_reports');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: the situation is same but how can we create for the my `Route::get('/admin/journal-agent-report',[JournalAgentReportController::class, 'index']);` also in which controller i have to add the above function